# How to serve Next.js SSG files with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

When doing `next export`, a folder called **build** will be generated. Currently I want to serve these static files using Express.js, here is the code:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.path);
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('App is running!'));
```

The problem here is when accessing paths other than  **/** such as **/blog**, it will redirect to **/** file (index.html), should I type in the routes one by one for each route, or is there another way to serve next SSG files with express?

Comment: You say the folder is called `out`, but in your `express.static` you use the name `build`?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Oops sorry, not out, I meant build

Comment: In that case, `GET /blog` would try to retrieve a file `build/blog`, does that exist (without a filename suffix)?

Comment: Yes, so here is the scenario:
1. Go to "/"
2. Navigate to "/blog" (works fine)
3. Refresh current page
4. Url in browser is domain.com/blog, but the content is from page "/"

Comment: So requests #2 and #3 go to the same URL `domain.com/blog`, but with different responses?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen exactly, so only when I access non-main route (#1), console.log(req.path) will log something, maybe because of the "\*", so I'm assuming that I need to create get endpoint for all routes instead of a single "\*" endpoint...

Comment: The `get('*')` route will be used if the `express.static` route cannot find a file.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I see, so maybe it needs to be domain.com/blog.html... Also for dynamic routes in build folder such as domain.com/category/art, it won't find the file (nextjs' filename for this will be category/[category].html

Comment: Sound like `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', req.path + '.html'));` instead of `express.static(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do something like this:

```
const dir = __dirname;
const sendFile = (file) => (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(dir, 'build', file));
const pathMap = new Set([
  '/settings', '/home' // All available static paths
]);

// For static files such as icons/images/etc
app.use(express.static(path.join(dir, 'build')));

// Nextjs dynamic routing
app.get('/blog/:blogID', sendFile('blog/[blogID].html'));
app.get('/category/:category', sendFile('category/[category].html'));

// Other paths, check whether to show page or 404(not found) page
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const p = req.path;
  if (pathMap.has(p)) res.sendFile(path.resolve(dir, 'build', `${p.slice(1)}.html`));
  else res.sendFile(path.resolve(dir, 'build', '404.html'));
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.